# Django: how to show related model fields in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new in Django 3.0 and I'm lost in this easy question, please help me.

I have 2 models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    fields...

class ProductType(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_types', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.Charfield(...)
```

In my template, I would like to show all the related product types and their fields to a specific product:

```
...
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.??? }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my view:

```
class ProductsView(ListView):
    collection = None
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 6
    template_name = 'shop/product/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        collection_name = self.kwargs['collection_name'] if 'collection_name' in self.kwargs else None
        if collection_name:
            collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, name=collection_name)
            products = products.filter(collection=collection)
        return products

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data(**self.kwargs)
        context['notification'] = Notification.objects.all()
        if 'collection_name' in self.kwargs:
            context['collection'] = get_object_or_404(Collection, name=self.kwargs['collection_name'])
            context['collection_name'] = self.kwargs['collection_name']
        context['collections'] = Collection.objects.all()
        return context
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the related `ProductType`s through a manager that has as name the value you specify as [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), so in this case:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% for type in product.product_types.all %}
        {{ type.color }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To boost efficiency, you can fetch all related `ProductType`s for the elements in the queryset with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
class ProductsView(ListView):
    # …

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('product_types').filter(available=True)
        collection_name = self.kwargs['collection_name'] if 'collection_name' in self.kwargs else None
        if collection_name:
            collection = get_object_or_404(Collection, name=collection_name)
            products = products.filter(collection=collection)
        return products
```

Comment: Excelent! Thank you. That worked! You're great for adding the doc as well!